# What is a CCD structure?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, projectile

In a exam paper for entry into Oxford University for physics, I came accross something which I hadn't met before, and I have no idea what the question is asking - none of my teachers could explain it to me, and I found nothing online. This is the paper

https://www2.physics.ox.ac.uk/sites/default/files/2011-02-14/pat_2013_paper_pdf_16194.pdf

and it is question 21 (c). I could do the rest of the question, I just don't understand what this one is asking.

The question is also pasted below, but seeing previous parts will give you the background of the question.

Now, instead of one particle, there are many particles, initially following the
same path as the first particle with speeds $v$, ranging between $v_1$ and $v_2$, at
the point of entry to the region where the force $F$ is acting. The detector
has a CCD like structure, meaning it is segmented into pixels of size $\Delta y$, the
same for all $y$.

What is the minimal spread of the speeds $\Delta v > 0$ such that $v$ and
$v + \Delta v < v_2$ are resolved by the detector?

Comment: CCD stands for [Charge-coupled device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge-coupled_device).

Answer (score 1):

A CCD is a [charge couple device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge-coupled_device). You can think of it as like a digital camera screen.

The detector is therefore made up of pixels of size $\Delta y$. You must find the minimum difference between $v_1$ and $v_2$ such that the two particles hit the detector with a separation at least $\Delta y$.

In part b) of the question you should have worked out $y$ as a function of $v$ so you should be able to write.

$$ y = f(v)$$
$$ y + \Delta y = f(v+\Delta v)$$

You should then be able to solve for $\Delta y$ I presume the $v$ terms will probably drop out.

You could also argue that you should solve for $2 \Delta y$ as if the particles are only one pixel apart then you cannot really distinguish them

Answer (score 0):

A CCD is a charge coupled detector - a photosensitive (usually) pixelated device. The "charge coupled" has to do with the way signals are transmitted to the readout electronics. For the purpose of this question you only need to know that this detector can resolve particles when they are $\Delta y$ apart - because those particles will hit different pixels on the detector and thus give rise to a different signal. Particles closer than that can hit the same pixel (although they *might* hit adjacent ones) and thus cannot be distinguished/resolved.